# Bootstrap grid for mobile, tablet, desktop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm learning bootstrap and trying to understand the grid system. I'm getting the hang of it but i need some clarification on something. I understand the columns should add up to 12 in a given row, with the exception of extra small devices.Why then is the column for small devices (col-sm-6) included here. This is from the bootstrap website. Thanks.

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if u assign `col-sm-6` content inside the `div`  it takes only 6/12 in  a row for small devices.

Comment: i understand that. my concern was the "adding up to 12". Perhaps i need to actually practice more to get it.

Comment: yes u can add `col-sm-12` to that div,  they just given to tell all possiblities.